# "Fire and Forget" Async Inside Distributed Transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, msdtc

We found a bug in our code that was introduced while converting a synchronous call to async.  Essentially we have an async call to infrastructure (MSMQ) that is not being awaited.  We see the problem, and know how to fix it.

The wrinkle is that this call is happening inside of a TransactionScope/Distributed Transaction.  It's not clear to me what the infrastructure is actually doing in a case where an action is not being awaited right before calling scope.Complete().

Does the transaction never get escalated to a Distributed Transaction?  Does the async statement get executed on a separate thread, and therefore doesn't participate in the ambient transaction?

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            _someService.PerformDatabaseAction(SomeType someType);

            //this call is async, but we don't await it
            _someOtherService.WriteToMsmqAsync(SomeOtherType someOtherType);

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

I believe if the second statement was enlisted and scope.Complete() was called, the transaction would roll back since all participants in the transaction were not yet ready to commit?

Comment: Are you aware of TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption? Because in your sample code you are not using it, so even await won't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, although I was not aware of it until I started researching this issue.

Comment: So . . . that might actually be the answer.  What would happen if TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption *was* used with the code as shown?

Comment: I have a feeling it might depend on implementation of WriteToMsmqAsync, maybe you can show it?

Comment: It's basically pseudo code.  It actually publishes a message using NServiceBus which is configured to use MSMQ.

Comment: Since you have race condition here, I'd say if transaction will be in time to enlist - the whole distributed transaction will fail OR scope will wait for second transaction to commit/fail (in scope timeout range). This needs to be tested since I did not find any info on that. If second function did not enlist into scope - it will complete just fine independent of scope.